# Update a value in a child node in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data in my state which resembles the json object below:

```
{
  "ID": "1234",
  "Name": "Craig",
  "Children": [
    {
      "Name": "Jim",
      "Id": "1",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sam",
      "Id": "2",
      "Enabled": false
    },
    {
      "Name": "Donald",
      "Id": "3",
      "Enabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I pass my 'Children' part to a component in props, that then renders them as a list of items, with a checkbox, allowing the user to enable and disable them. I also pass a callback function. My plan was, when ever a user changes the state of a checkbox, pass the new value of the checkbox, as well as the child ID, back to my parent controller:

So, if I changed Jim to false, I pass back {1 and false}..

Then, and this is where I am stuck, I need to find that child object in my state, and change the Enabled value.

Is there a javascript way to do this safely, with the state? I was hoping there would be a c# version like:

```
var child = (from c in state.data.Children where c.Id = 1);
```

Then set that value. `(child.enabled = newValue)`.

Bit first off, Linq isn't an option, but also, updating state isn't as easy. I need to setState.

OR, do I siply post back the whole props value with the updated values, and in my parent component, somehow replace the whole 'Children' object, with the new value. Which seems like a bad idea, as I'd be changing the entire Children node, for one small change.

Comment: as for last paragraph: it is correct and expected approach in react.don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, I would pass a closure to the child component via props. This allows the child to be very "dumb" and not need to worry about where it belongs in its parent array.

```
class Container extends Component {
  handleOnChange = (index) => () => {
    this.setState({
      data: data.map((node, i) => index !== i 
        ? node 
        : ({ ...node, Enabled: !node.Enabled }))
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.state.data.Children.map((child, i) => (
          <ChildDataNode isEnabled={child.Enabled} onChange={this.handleOnChange(i)} />
        ))}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// child
const ChildDataNode = ({ isEnabled, onChange }) => (
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} value={isEnabled} />
  </div>
);
```

To do the same without treating `handleOnChange` as a closure, this would suffice:

```
class Container extends Component {
  handleOnChange = (index) => {
    this.setState({
      data: data.map((node, i) => index !== i 
        ? node 
        : ({ ...node, Enabled: !node.Enabled }))
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.state.data.Children.map((child, i) => (
          <ChildDataNode index={i} isEnabled={child.Enabled} onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
        ))}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// child
const ChildDataNode = ({ isEnabled, onChange, index }) => (
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={onChange(index)} value={isEnabled} />
  </div>
);
```

Six to one, half dozen the other. I prefer the former solution as it keeps the child as dumb as possible.

Comment: Thanks Daniel... Let me try work out what you're doing there. :) I'm not sure what's meant by " pass a closure to the child component via props"

Answer (score 0):

Something like below.

You need to pass id and enabled value to the callback event handler and in the event handler function assign the previous data children state to a local variable. Then, do the map on children and do id match and override the object.

You can check below solution for better understanding

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      data: {
        "ID": "1234",
        "Name": "Craig",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Name": "Jim",
            "Id": "1",
            "Enabled": true
          },
          {
            "Name": "Sam",
            "Id": "2",
            "Enabled": false
          },
          {
            "Name": "Donald",
            "Id": "3",
            "Enabled": true
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  }

  //callback function
  handleCheckbox = (id, enabled) => {
    let children = this.state.data.Children;
    let rows = [];
    children.map((d, i) => {
      if(id == d.Id){
        let obj = {};
        obj.Enabled = enabled;
        obj.Id = id;
        obj.Name = d.Name;
        rows.push(obj);
      }else{
        rows.push(d);
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      data.Children : rows
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```